How to fix querying on "Name" Table?
My API request to salesforce for fetching columns from table Name is failing with:
entity type Name does not support query
The query that I am trying to do is like: SELECT FirstName from Name where FirstName='Test'

As per the documentation,

Non-queryable object that provides information about foreign key
traversals when the foreign key has more than one parent.
This object is used to retrieve information from related records where
the related record can be from more than one object type (a
polymorphic foreign key). For example, the owner of a case can be
either a user or a group (queue). This object allows retrieval of the
owner name, whether the owner is a user or a group (queue). You can
use a describe call to access the information about parents for an
object, or you can use the who, what, or owner fields (depending on
the object) in SOQL queries. This object can’t be directly accessed.

